# Cannot convert from List to array in Arrays intersection

Tags: java, android

I have tried to intersect 2 double arrays in this way

```
public double[] intersect(double[] a, double[] b) {
        List<double[]> aList =  Arrays.asList(a);
        List<double[]> bList =  Arrays.asList(b);
        aList.retainAll(bList);
        double[] c = aList.toArray(new double[aList.size()]);
    }
```

Unfortunately the line

```
double[] c = aList.toArray(new double[aList.size()]);
```

doesn't compile

How should I fix the issue

Comment: Yet tried with no result

Comment: You do not even post the compile error. You're not exactly helping us debug this.

Comment: You need `List<Double>` since the primitive can't be used with generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit your code to have sense.

```
public Double[] intersect(Double[] a, Double[] b) {
        List<Double> aList =  Arrays.asList(a); // List<double[]> this is bad!
        List<Double> bList =  Arrays.asList(b);
        aList.retainAll(bList);
        return aList.toArray(new Double[aList.size()]);            
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to use double primitive?

Comment: see that you have anothers errors too!, use `Double[]` , then this is a valid code for example `double a = array[0];`

Comment: @AndreaF There's no out-of-the-box method in the Java SDK for that, but you could use a library. For example, [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has [Doubles.toArray](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29).

Answer (score 3):

The `List#toArray` is a generic method, which can be seen by its signature:

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

Since primitives cannot be used with generics you must use the wrapper class `Double`

```
Double[] c = aList.toArray(new Double[aList.size()]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... Is there no way to use double primitive?

Comment: Why so bent on using a primitive if the object wrapper works just fine? I suggest doing some research on primitives and their respective object counterparts.